# react with TS - useNavigate() with react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The App.tsx -

```
import React from 'react'; import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

import AppView from './App.view';

interface Props { }

const App: React.FC<Props> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props>)
=> {   const navigate = useNavigate();   const isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('token');

  return (
      <AppView
        isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
        navigate={navigate}
      ></AppView>   ); };

App.displayName = 'App'; App.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(App);
```

The App.view.tsx -

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { 
  Route,
  Routes,
  NavigateFunction,
  BrowserRouter,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/Login/Login'));
const Table = React.lazy(() => import('./components/pages/Table/Table'));

interface Props {
  readonly isLoggedIn: string | null;
  readonly navigate: NavigateFunction;
}

const AppView: React.FC<Props> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props>) => (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            {props.isLoggedIn ? 
              <Route path="/table" element={<Table />} /> :
              props.navigate('/login', { replace: true })
            }
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Suspense>
);

AppView.displayName = 'AppView';
AppView.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(AppView);
```

The error -
`Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

Can't understand the problem. Tried to look at -
https://typescript.tv/react/upgrade-to-react-router-v6/

My packege.json -

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
```

devDependencies -

```
"@types/react": "^17.0.36",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2"
```

I would like to navigate to /table only when isLoggenIn === true

Comment: you only can use `useNavigate()` hooks on Component that wrapped by `<BrowserRouter>` Provider.
in your case, you can use `useNavigate()` hooks inside your `/login` and '/table` pages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that navigate is being called outside of a `<Router>`. I know, I know, your intent was that it isn't actually invoked until the `props.navigate()` in App.View.tsx. But it's defined in App.tsx.

Solution:
Move the `<BrowserRouter>` from App.View.tsx to App.tsx and wrap your `<AppView>` component like this:

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <AppView
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      navigate={navigate}>
    </AppView>
  <BrowserRouter>
   );
 };
```

Now I realize that this is violating your desire to use Presentational Components and Container Components. If you want to continue to do that, you'll just move your `<BrowserRouter>` up *one level* to it's parent Presentational component. No big deal.

But I warn you that most developers are rejecting that pattern in modern React. ... even [Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).